# Update all objects where create new one

Tags: c#

I have a Languages class in which i use the excellibrary. I have an .xls file in which i have three columns. The first is used to check if the key phrase is used in the document and then i have one column for each language i use. I would like to create a transactionField object for every row of the document. I try to do that but every time i create a new object all the objects that was created before take the values of the last object created. Camn you please explain me where i am wrong and how can i correct that issue?
This is where the mistake happen

```
  TranslationField tnf = new TranslationField();
                     tnf.Used = false;
                     tnf.Strings = values;
                     Translations.Add(sKey, tnf);

   public class Languages
   {
    public static bool Setup()
      {
        SupportedLanguages.Clear();
        SupportedLanguages.Add(csDefaultLang);

        try
        {
            Workbook book = Workbook.Load(sPath);
            Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];

            KeyStringHelper values = new KeyStringHelper();
            TranslationNeedle tnl;
            List<string> columns = new List<string>();
            string sKey = "";

            // traverse rows by Index
            for (int rowIndex = sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex; rowIndex <= sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex; rowIndex++)
            {
                Row row = sheet.Cells.GetRow(rowIndex);
                row.FirstColIndex = 1;

                for (int colIndex = row.FirstColIndex; colIndex <= row.LastColIndex; colIndex++)
                {
                    Cell cell = row.GetCell(colIndex);

                    // the first excel row is assumed to be columns names
                    if (rowIndex == sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex)
                    {
                        //Columns names correctly formatted
                        columns.Add(char.ToUpper(cell.StringValue[0]) + cell.StringValue.Substring(1).ToUpper());
                        //Register every language inside the xls
                        SupportedLanguages.Add(char.ToUpper(cell.StringValue[0]) + cell.StringValue.Substring(1).ToUpper());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (colIndex - row.FirstColIndex == 0)
                            sKey = cell.StringValue.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
                        else
                            values.Add(columns[colIndex - row.FirstColIndex], cell.StringValue.Replace("\r\n", "\n"));
                    }
                }

                // add the cell values to Translations Dictionary
                if (rowIndex != sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex)
                {
                     TranslationField tnf = new TranslationField();
                     tnf.Used = false;
                     tnf.Strings = values;
                     Translations.Add(sKey, tnf);
                }
              }

            //other stuff
         }
       }
```

Here is the class TranslationField

```
class TranslationField
{
public bool Used = false;
public KeyStringHelper Strings = new KeyStringHelper();
}
```

Comment: Please reproduce this as a [mcve]. Note that you haven't shown your `TranslationField` class which is likely to be where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, edit the answer

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried, so far? Based on your code, I don't see where the code is going wrong. Let us know where the code is going wrong, that works much better in StackOverflow rather than asking "how do I solve this functional requirement?"... and your question sounds a lot closer to the latter than the former, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing the same `KeyStringHelper` instance (`values`) for every `TranslationField`.  So every `TranslationField` instance in your `Translations` collection is referencing the same `KeyStringHelper` instance.

It looks like you need to move the line

```
KeyStringHelper values = new KeyStringHelper();
```

inside the outer `for` loop.